# String replace to certain format

Tags: php, str-replace

May I know how to use string replace to a certain symbols in the character with follow the format?

Below is example what I want the results, I just want to replace in front number inside the symbols:

```html
Before                                                  |     After (Expected result)
100-1-1 Penggubalan/Penyediaan/Pindaan Undang-Undang        100-1/1 Penggubalan/Penyediaan/Pindaan Undang-Undang
100-1-1-16 Undang-Undang Kecil Hotel/test                   100-1/1/16 Undang-Undang Kecil Hotel/test
```

Format inside number with symbol need to change, XXX is fixed number total format,() is random number total format:

```html
xxx-()-()      change to  xxx-()/()
xxx-()-()-()   change to  xxx-()/()/()
```

Below is I've tried the coding:

```html
$try = "100-1-1 Penggubalan/Penyediaan/Pindaan Undang-Undang";
$try_1 = "100-1-1-16 Undang-Undang Kecil Hotel/test";
$test = str_replace('-','/',trim($try));
$test_2 = str_replace('-','/',trim($try_2));

echo $test;
echo $test_2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a very naive approach, but it works.

```php
<?php 
function replaceHyphen($str) {
    $i = -1;
    for($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        if($str[$i] == "-") break;
    }
    for($i++; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        if($str[$i] == "-") $str[$i] = '/';
        if($str[$i] == " ") break;
    }
    return $str;
}
$try = "100-1-1 Penggubalan/Penyediaan/Pindaan Undang-Undang";
$try_1 = "100-1-1-16 Undang-Undang Kecil Hotel/test";

echo(replaceHyphen($try));
echo(replaceHyphen($try_1));
?>
```

Comment: php and javascript

Comment: Let's continue the discussion on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221303/php-string-replace-discussion

Comment: Thanks，Debargha Roy. I found the mistake. Your method is correct